# Stopping NSScrollView at a target content offset?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview

In iOS we're able able stop a "fling" with one of the delegate methods on `UIScrollView` and setting a `targetContentOffset`.

In macOS AppKit however, delegate of a `NSScrollView` isn't publicly available and there seems to be no way of controlling the stopping distance of a scroll. I've got responsive / live scrolling working on a `NSScrollView` with a custom `NSView`, and would like to limit the amount of `pages` a user can scroll at a time. Right now, a single fling on the track pad takes you to the 20th page or something (due to responsive scrolling), how do I limit this?

Also, I'd like to limit the user to be able to only scroll to the next page, before requiring another vertical swipe on the trackpad (so page by page vertical swiping).